# Variável Global - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá!

Quero exibir um dado($variavel) em um footer.

Da forma que está abaixo, funciona e a variável `$operador` é exibida corretamente em todas as opções/telas que eu clicar.

```
<?php $operador = $this->session->userdata('nome'); ?>

<div id="footer" class="span12"> <?php echo date('Y'); ?> | Versão: <?php echo $operador; ?>
```

Mas não quero exibir uma `$variável` da session.

Então criei um controller/modal/view chamado **SISTEMA**.

Neste controller tenho o `idSistema, nome, data_registro, date_expiracao, licenca, versao`.

Portanto, quero exibir no footer a **versao**.

Então, tentei da seguinte forma:

`<div id="footer" class="span12"> <?php echo date('Y'); ?> | Versão: <?php foreach ($results as $r) { echo $r->versao; }?></div>`

Mas isto só funciona se eu estiver na opção **SISTEMA**, caso eu clique em outro opção, onde deveria mostrar a versão do sistema, é exibido a mensagem que a variável results não foi definida.

Como posso definir esta variável como global??

Abaixo, parte do código da função no controller sistema.

`$this->data['results'] = $this->sistemas_model->get('sistemas','idSistemas,nome, dt_registro,dt_expiracao,licenca,versao','',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

        $this->data['view'] = 'sistemas/sistemas';
        $this->load->view('tema/topo',$this->data);`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Queria te ajudar mas não entendi direito. Não entedi o que quer dizer com variável global.  O quem tem em $this->data['results']? Precisa fazer o `foreach`? Apenas isso não resolve: `<div id="footer" class="span12"> <?php echo date('Y'); ?> | Versão: <?php echo $results->versao ?></div>`

Comment: Não funciona.. versao está vindo de array.. Por este motivo eu coloquei o foreach.

Comment: Quero transformar os valores de **results** em variáveis globais como  a session, que posso obter os valores em qualquer pagina.

Comment: qual a versão do codeigniter?

Comment: A aplicação Está na versão 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar a [função nativa do codeigniter `vars()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::vars)

Você basicamente precisa definir quais variaveis quer tornar globais usando

```
$this->load->vars();
```

Coloque esta função na classe "base" do codeigniter `CI_Controller` como no exemplo abaixo;

```
class CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        ...
        $this->load->vars(['name' => 'variabel global']);
        // Dentro da função vars você pode chamar 
        // uma outra função que retorna um array com os dados do sistema
    }
```

Agora é só usar a variavel na view `$name`.

Comment: Está seria a forma mais fácil? Como seria se eu criasse um helper e carrega-lo na view?

Comment: alterei a resposta.